# NodeJs/React - Multer upload multiple file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multer

i've written my backend with NodeJS and my frontend with React.

I use redux and axios in frontend for push CRUD operations and i want to upload five mp3 files to backend with multer.

So i've set multer as  the following code

```
const fileStorageImage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "audio");
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + "-" + file.originalname);
    }
});

app.use(multer({storage: fileStorageImage}).array('file', 20));
```

and set my route as the following

```
router.post("audios", (req, res, next) => {

    console.log(req.files)

}
```

So on my output i expect to see print my files uploaded, but otherwise my output was 'undefined'.

My question is: How can i upload multiple file on multer and get this file data from my router.post()?

NB = On frontend i use `<input name="file" multiple />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multer in your route as middleware like

```
router.post("audios", multerconfig, (req, res, next) => {

     console.log(req.files)

}
```

[Go here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54306864/service-for-uploading-multiple-file-using-multer-in-node-js/54307438?noredirect=1#comment95436818_54307438) I have answered in detail to a question on  this site